# How to ALTER COLUMN using AS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a question about column modification. I would like to change column content.

I cannot use the UPDATE command, because the most important thing is that the column changes, in case of changes in the columns from which this one is concatenated. I have used code below

```
ALTER TABLE test_table
ALTER COLUMN col4 AS CONCAT(col1, ABS(col2), TRIM(col3))
```

Is it possible to define an existing column in this way? In my case, I have to make sucha an operation on primary key column so I would prefer not to delete this one and ADD new.

I will be grateful for any tip

Comment: You cannot `ALTER` a computed column. You must `DROP` and re-`ADD` it.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thank you very much